# React Nouislider - Issues with onChange, and setState, slider resets to 0, and no value in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nouislider

I'm creating a simple application with React, my knowledge of React is about a week old, so please excuse any oversights that I may have had, or any overall idiocy when it comes to the code I have written to try and get this to work.

I am using the React version of Nouislider:
https://github.com/algolia/react-nouislider

And referencing the original documentation for Nouislider here:
https://refreshless.com/nouislider/

I am able to create a slider, and fire a function using the onChange prop. At first I logged the output to the console, and verified that the value was correct. However the moment I try and update the state using this.setState, it snaps the slider back to 0, and the state gets an undefined value instead of the value of the slider.

Here is my current code:

The constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    matchWinnerScore: "",
  }
  this.handleWinnerClick = this.handleWinnerClick.bind(this);
}
```

The slider, inside the render function:

```
<Nouislider
    start={[0]}
    connect={[true, false]}
    step={1}
    range={{ min: 0, max: 30 }}
    onChange={this.handleWinnerScoreChange}
/>
```

The onChange function:

```
handleWinnerScoreChange(event) {
  console.log(event[0]);
  this.setState({
       matchWinnerScore: event[0]
    });
  console.log(this.matchWinnerScore);
}
```

In the console, the output is:

```
14.00
undefined
```

Any help, thoughts, or advice is greatly welcomed. I've hit a brick wall and need a fresh set of eyes to guide me in the right direction.

Look forward to your replies!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue with this library:
https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider

Unfortunately, I had to create a child component for my text (or whatever you are binding the slider value to) with a ref. It works but obviously not ideal to use ref on such a basic component.

**Parent Component (only relevant shown)**

---

```
  onChangeSlide = (values, handle, unencoded, tap, positions) => {
    let { challengeObject } = this.props;

    this.refs['ProgressText' + challengeObject.id].updateProgress(parseInt(values[0]))
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let uiSlider = this.refs['NoUiSlider' + challengeObject.id].slider
    uiSlider.on('update', this.onChangeSlide);
    uiSlider.on('end', function () {
      //save it to db
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, challengeObject } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Nouislider
          ref={'NoUiSlider' + challengeObject.id}
          start={[challengeObject.progress['startValue']]}
          connect={[true, false]}
          step={1}
          range={{
            min: 0,
            max: challengeObject.progress['targetValue'] 
          }}
        />

        <ProgressText
          ref={'ProgressText' + challengeObject.id}
          startValue={challengeObject.progress['targetValue']}
          endValue={challengeObject.progress['targetValue']}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Child Component**

---

```
import React from "react";

class ProgressText extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        startValue: this.props.startValue
    }
  }

  updateProgress = (val) => {
      this.setState({ startValue: val })
  }

  render() {
    let { endValue } = this.props;
    let { startValue } = this.state

    return (
        <span>  
            {startValue + '/' + endValue}
        </span>
    );
  }
}

export default ProgressText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue being that NouiSlider could not directly update the state in any form of callback thus my solution was to have Nouislider indirectly update the state. My solution was I had the "onUpdate" event update the inner text of an element linked to a ref that displayed the value to the user. Then the "onChange" event (which is called after drag is over) updates the state of a random state that was linked to a useEffect that had that random state as a dependency. Then inside that useEffect I would update the state based on the current related ref's values. The code looked something like this:

```
    const [form, setForm] = useState({...state})
    const [random, setRandom] = useState(null);
    const noUiSliderValue = useRef(null);
    useEffect(()=>{ setForm({...form, value:noUiSlider.current.innerText})}, [random]}
```

Then for the NouiSlider element:

```
    <Nouislider
     start={[0]}
     connect={[true, false]}
     step={1}
     range={{ min: 0, max: 30 }}
     onChange={(range)=>setRandom(range)}
     onUpdate={(range) => noUiSliderValue.current.innerText=range[0]}
     />
```

I have no idea why NouiSlider has such strange behaviors with state-related callbacks but this was just a janky fix to fix a janky issue.